# MakeFile destination directory

Tags: c++, makefile

I have my codes in src folder.
src/Client contains a makefile to create a Client application.
src/Server contains a makefile to create a Client application.
I have a bin file in the same folder as src.
Folder named ad contains src and bin.
in bin i have a makefile

```
all: 
    cd ../src/Server; make
    cd ../src/Client; make

clean: 
    cd ../src/Server; make clean
    cd ../src/Client; make clean
```

My problem is that i want all my executable files in bin but now they are created in Server and Client folder.

My makefile in Client folder:

```
# Define the compiler and the linker. The linker must be defined since
# the implicit rule for linking uses CC as the linker. g++ can be
# changed to clang++.
CXX = g++
CC  = g++

# Define preprocessor, compiler, and linker flags. Uncomment the # lines
# if you use clang++ and wish to use libc++ instead of libstd++.
CPPFLAGS  =-I.. -I ../database

CXXFLAGS =  -g -O2 -Wall -W -pedantic-errors
CXXFLAGS += -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wold-style-cast 
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 
LDFLAGS =   -g -L.. -L../database
#CPPFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
#CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
#LDFLAGS +=  -stdlib=libc++

# Libraries
LDLIBS = -lclientserver -ldatabase

# Targets
PROGS = interface


all: $(PROGS)

# Targets rely on implicit rules for compiling and linking
# The dependency on libclientserver.a is not defined.
interface: interface.o com.o ans.o

# Phony targets
.PHONY: all clean

# Standard clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o $(PROGS)

# Generate dependencies in *.d files
%.d: %.cc
    @set -e; rm -f $@; \
         $(CPP) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
         sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
         rm -f $@.$$$$

# Include the *.d files
SRC = $(wildcard *.cc)
include $(SRC:.cc=.d)
```

What should i change in this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, your main makefile is what builds the executable. The auxiliary ones are supposed to make the object files. In this case it would be practical to just move the executables to the root folder:

```
mv src/Client/$(EXECUTABLE) src/bin
mv src/Server/$(EXECUTABLE) src/bin
```

If you really want to do it right, link the object files from the main make

```
all:
      $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CLIENT_FOLDER)/*.o $(SERVER_FOLDER)/*.o $(BIN_FOLDER)/$(EXECUTABLE)
```

And make the aux files just compile

Comment: I did like this
interface: interface.o com.o ans.o
 $(CXX) -o ../../bin/$@ $^ $(LDLIBS) $(LDFLAGS)
same in the other one.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Define the compiler and the linker. The linker must be defined since
# the implicit rule for linking uses CC as the linker. g++ can be
# changed to clang++.
CXX = g++
CC  = g++

# Define preprocessor, compiler, and linker flags. Uncomment the # lines
# if you use clang++ and wish to use libc++ instead of libstd++.
CPPFLAGS  =-I.. -I ../database

CXXFLAGS =  -g -O2 -Wall -W -pedantic-errors
CXXFLAGS += -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wold-style-cast 
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 
LDFLAGS =   -g -L.. -L../database
#CPPFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
#CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
#LDFLAGS +=  -stdlib=libc++

# Libraries
LDLIBS = -lclientserver -ldatabase

# Targets
PROGS = interface


all: $(PROGS)

# Targets rely on implicit rules for compiling and linking
# The dependency on libclientserver.a is not defined.
interface: interface.o com.o ans.o
     $(CXX) -o ../../bin/$@ $^ $(LDLIBS) $(LDFLAGS)
# Phony targets
.PHONY: all clean

# Standard clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o $(PROGS)

# Generate dependencies in *.d files
%.d: %.cc
    @set -e; rm -f $@; \
         $(CPP) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
         sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
         rm -f $@.$$$$

# Include the *.d files
SRC = $(wildcard *.cc)
include $(SRC:.cc=.d)
```

This works